# Unable to upload XMLHttpRequest file

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

Good afternoon to all users. Recently faced a file transfer problem. And along with the task, a bunch of problems appeared: There is a js code like this:

```
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})
;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})
;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)
function preventDefaults (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}
function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}
function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('highlight')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  let dt = e.dataTransfer
  let files = dt.files
  handleFiles(files)
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function uploadFile(file, i) { 
  var url = '/temp.php'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData(document.forms.myform)
  xhr.open('POST', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
  
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    }
    else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
    }
  })
  
  formData.append('file', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}

let uploadProgress = []
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')
function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []
  for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}
function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}
```

And here's a html form like this with a php handler:

```
<div id="drop-area">
    <form name="myform" class="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="gallery"></div>    
        <p><input type="file" id="fileElem" name="Test[]" style="font-size: 15px;" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"></p>
        <label class="button" for="fileElem">Choose files</label>
        <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
        <div id="gallery"></div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error = UPLOAD_ERROR_OK) {
        $uploaddir = "/mnt/";
        $uploaddir .= basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]);
        if(file_exists(uploaddir)) {
            unlink(uploaddir);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploaddir);
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploaddir);
        }
}}
?>
```

Of course nothing works: files are not transferred to the folder. What am I doing wrong? Why are the files not being transferred?
Please help the young tudent.

Comment: Ringing the bell ... `if ($error = UPLOAD_ERROR_OK) {...}`

Comment: If you mean that this is the problem, then why when I did exactly the same php handler for clicking a button, then everything worked. Could you please explain in more detail what is the matter.

Comment: `=` is an assignment, maybe it's not the issue here, though. How is `file` created in the JS part?

Comment: `if ($error = UPLOAD_ERROR_OK)` will prevent the execution of that whole following block for sure here, because the value of `UPLOAD_ERROR_OK` is `0`. And the value of an assignment expression is the assigned value, so that’s basically a `if(0)` right there.

Comment: I have exactly the same handler for adding files on click of a button and it works fine, 
so I think it's not about "if", although I may be wrong

Comment: In general, I'd advice against arguing with the guidance you're getting at SO, the vaste majority of it is correct, and if a comment is incorrect, it's very quickly issued in other comments. Please read CBroe's comment over and over again until you understand what CBroe says ... It is possible, that the error is in the code example only, and your real code does have a comparison operator, though.

Comment: I solved my question, thanks, but this was not the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, the error was in js:

```
formData.append('file[]', file);
```